# How to avoid redundant code writing promises?

Tags: node.js, promise, request-promise

I have a file where multiple export functions that are invoked from api's and each of these methods will make some get/post inside the function. 
so my questions is for Promise.all that looks redundant to me is there better approach to achieve this using one private method handler that can be implemented or invoked from each of those export function and return response.

main.ts

```
export function getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {

  const p1 = Promise.resolve("data1");
  const p2 = Promise.resolve("data2");

    Promise.all([p1,p2])
        .then(function(results) {
            res.json(results);

        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });

}

export function getRanks(req: Request, res: Response) {

   const p1 = Promise.resolve("data3");
   const p2 = Promise.resolve("data4");

    Promise.all([p1,p2])
        .then(function(results) {
            res.json(results);

        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });

}
```

Comment: No different than any other type of code.  Factor common code into a shared function which you can call from both methods.  And, this is not specific to code that uses promises at all.

Comment: So is the `Promise.all` code consistent across all the functions?

Comment: in some cases i might have to get nested values but so far it is consistent

Comment: If Promise.all is needed, it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do exactly what you wrote - create function that does the general handling.

```
export function getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
  const p1 = Promise.resolve("data1");
  const p2 = Promise.resolve("data2");
  sendResponse(req, res, [p1,p2]);
}

export function getRanks(req: Request, res: Response) {
   const p1 = Promise.resolve("data3");
   const p2 = Promise.resolve("data4");
   sendResponse(req, res, [p1,p2]);
}

function sendResponse(req, res, promises) {
    Promise.all(promises)
        .then(function(results) {
            res.json(results);

        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
}
```

PS: You should have some `res` handling in .catch (`res.end()` or `res.status(500); res.json({error: e})`) otherwise the request will be hanging on for 30-90sec (based on your settings)

Comment: Note, the `.catch()` needs to also send a response (probably an error response).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a separate catch() for getUser and getRanks()?

Comment: @jfriend00 - I wrote that into an answer

Comment: @dasfdsa - why?

Comment: So that both of these can handle error in their own ways, maybe? (Its more of a question than a comment)

Comment: thats how promise.all is designed if one promise fails entire method fails

Answer (score 0):

In case `p1`, etc. promises are really created `Promise.resolve`, it could be omitted; `Promise.all` accepts regular values.

It could be written with `async..await` in more succinct manner:

```
export async function getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
  ...
  try {
    const results = await Promise.all([p1, p2]);
    res.json(results);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

At this point functions don't need to be DRYed any further.